# Send Email from windows phone 8 with custom credentials

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I need to send email programmatically from my windows phone 8 (c#). I tried with "EmailComposeTask" and it considers the email configured in the device as sender.I want to give custom sender credentials which might not be same as that of configured credentials.

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();   
emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";//enter code here    
emailComposeTask.Body = "Append all your control strings here";    
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";    
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";    
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";  
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

Here I need to specify the sender credentials also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the sender credentials programmatically. there is no such property exposed by `EmailComposeTask` class. You can use other services like `SendGrid` etc. for this.
For reference see [Class specification on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)